# How to Add button or label to iwatch programatically

Tags: ios, uibutton, apple-watch

I was tinkering with the `WKInterface` and Apple Watch apps and was just wondering how to add a subview like a `UIButton` or `UILabel`.

It seems that

```
UIButton *whatever = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[self.view addsubview:whatever];
```

does not work for the iWatch extension. Mainly the `[self.view addsubview: ]` part doesnt seem to work.

Does anyone know how to add a view programatically for apple watch or do I have to use the interface builder and drag and drop these objects.

Comment: I think this link will help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28694819/3378413

Answer (score 3):

You have to use interface builder. You cannot allocate any UI objects by yourself.

[Creating an Interface Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH13-SW1)

> You create interface objects indirectly by adding the object to your
>   storyboard scene and referring to it from your interface controller.
>   After adding an element to your storyboard, create an outlet for it in
>   your interface controller. During the initialization of your interface
>   controller, watchOS creates the interface objects for all of your
>   connected outlets automatically. **You never create the interface
>   objects yourself.**