# I have to add a list of button programmatically

Tags: swift, button, watchkit

How can I add some buttons programmatically in swift 2 using WatchKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't dynamically create views in WatchKit. You need to create
>   your entire interface in a storyboard. You can have elements of your
>   storyboard hidden and then programmatically unhide them.

Reference : [Create imageView programmatically in Watch Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658498/create-imageview-programmatically-in-watch-kit)

You can create table instead of the buttons. So, you can get multiple clickable links.

Here is tutorial by @natashatherobot http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-create-table/

Snippet from the tutorial :

```
private func loadTableData() {
    minionTable.setNumberOfRows(minions.count, withRowType: "MinionTableRowController")
    for (index, minionName) in enumerate(minions) {
        let row = minionTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! MinionTableRowController
        row.interfaceLabel.setText(minionName)
        row.interfaceImage.setImage(UIImage(named: minionName))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to use table but I am not finding good examples. Have you got any one?

Comment: @LucaMarconato Check the updated link about tutorial

Comment: @LucaMarconato Welcome anytime. :)